# Why my ScrollView gets hidden?

Tags: android

As usual fighting with ScrollViews...

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scinputscrollbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonscontainer"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/congratsinput"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/inputting"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/inputsite"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/inputoterinfo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <com.examples.android.calendar.ActionEditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/yesreminders"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonscontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/roundrectanglebutton"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/roundrectanglebutton"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/no"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is the result I get...**

[image]

**This is the desired result:**

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this configuration lead to the desired results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scinputscrollbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonscontainer"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/congratsinput"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/inputting"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/inputsite"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/inputoterinfo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <com.examples.android.calendar.ActionEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/yesreminders"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonscontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/roundrectanglebutton"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/roundrectanglebutton"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/no"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the height of the `ScrollView` to `match_parent`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `android:fillViewport="true"` to your `ScrollView`.

**EDIT :**

Also, you do not need a `RelativeLayout`. If you just want your `ScrollView` and your `LinearLayout` to be one above the other, replace the `RelativeLayout` by a `LinearLayout` and set the `orientation` to `vertical`.

Comment: thanks a lot! indeed with android:fillViewport="true" it works. The point is that I need the buttons to stay at the bottom, and the upper part to scroll...

Comment: In your `layout` containing the buttons, did you try to set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` ?

Comment: You can also try what @user2558882 said, setting `android:layout_below="@+id/scinputscrollbar"`

Comment: android:layout_below="@+id/scinputscrollbar" is not working. only a fraction of the buttons appear

Comment: What happens when you scroll ? Everything scrolls or just the scrollview ?

Comment: Nothing scrolls ! :-)

Comment: Hmm just one question, are you sure you need a `scrollview`? :) On the screenshot it does not look like it. Could you provide a screenshot of what you have now ?

Comment: I need a ScrollView beacause the EditText in the middle is multilne and potentially the user might imput several lines... :-(((

Comment: If you hard-code a high number of lines in your xml files, what is the result ? The button disappear ? Did you try the `layout_alignParentBottom` as I mentionned above ? (I'm trying to undestand :) )